# Splitting Shopify Multi Single Line Metafield to HTML List

Tags: shopify, liquid

This displays on the front end:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id == variant.id %}
{{ variant.metafields.reels.spool.value }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This does not:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id == variant.id %}
    {%- assign speclist = variant.metafields.reels.spool.value | metafield_tag -%}  
      {% if speclist != blank %}
      <ul>
        {% for speclist-item in variant.metafields.reels.spool.value -%}
          <li> {{ speclist-item }}</li>
        {%- endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The top displays Variant values for a Shopify Single Line Text Metafield (list of values)
I would like to display the values as an html list

Any ideas?

Comment: you need ti share the structure of data, and also output of 1st code, because 1st and 2nd code above listed are separate logic.

Comment: Does the first code block display a series of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

There is a liquid string filter called `newline_to_br` ([reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters#newline_to_br)), using the filter you should be able to split the lines like so in liquid:

```
{% assign lines = "line one\nline two\nline three" | newline_to_br | split: '<br />' %}

<ul>
  {% for line in lines %}
    <li>{{ line | strip }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Demo:
[image: demo]